# Statistics - Chebychev's Inequalities

Tags: statistics

1) A box contains 100 tickets labeled with numbers. The average of the labels is -47.1 and the SD of the labels is 3.2. Sixteen tickets will be drawn independently at random with replacement from the box. The chance that the absolute value of the difference between the sample sum of the labels on the tickets and -753.6 does not exceed 90.88 is at least _____?

I've calculated the Expected Value and Standard Error but can't seem to find the correct final answer.

2) A box contains 100 tickets labeled with numbers. None of the labels is negative. The average of the labels is 66.1. Twenty tickets will be drawn independently at random with replacement from the box. The chance that the sample sum does not exceed 2776.2 is at least/at most ____?

I've been stuck on both questions for sometime, would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: For the first problem, what was your standard deviation? (Just checking you got it right.)

Comment: SD was given (3.2), Standard Error was 12.8 [(16)^1/2*(3.2)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: Let $Y$ be the sum. Then $E(Y)=(16)(-47.1)=-753.6$ and $Y$ has standard deviation $\sigma=(4)(3.2)=12.8$.

Note that $90.88=(7.1)\sigma$. The Chebyshev Inequality says 
$$\Pr(|Y-E(Y)|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
So the probability the absolute value of the difference is $\ge 90.88$ is $\frac{1}{(7.1)^2}$, and therefore our required probability is $1-\frac{1}{(7.1)^2}$.

Second Problem: The inequality we use is more commonly called Markov's Inequality. It says that for a non-negative random variable $Y$ with mean $E(Y)$, and positive $a$, we have 
$$\Pr(Y\ge a)\le \frac{E(Y)}{a}.$$
Here $E(Y)=(20)(66.1)$. The rest should follow from Markov's Inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.

Comment: @user355068: You are welcome. I left some stuff to do in the second problem. If there are any difficulties, please leave a message.